# Make a custom field in admin post.php read only

Tags: theme-development, custom-field, filters, post-meta

How I make a custom field (which can be enabled from the screen options) in the post edit page read only and not editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making the custom field read-only, you can hide a custom field by prefixing the name of the custom field with an underscore.

e.g `_custom_field_name`

You can hide the field by disabling the input boxes using replacing **`CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME`** with the name of your custom field.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    metaName = jQuery("#postcustom input[value='CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME']").attr("id");
    metaValue = metaName.replace("key", "value");

    metaName.prop('disabled', true);
    metaValue.prop('disabled', true);
})
```

You would need to put the jQuery code in a js file in your Parent or Child theme and enqueue it on the `post.php` page using:

```
function add_admin_scripts( $hook ) {
    if ( $hook == 'post-new.php' || $hook == 'post.php' ) {
        wp_enqueue_script(  'myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/myscript.js' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_admin_scripts', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: i was going to do the same but was thinking of the php way

Comment: also what if the user has disabled javascript

Comment: I still believe it's best to hide the custom field by prefixing it with an underscore.